# Need Number validation regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

The following point must be considered before creating a regular expression:

> Add +(plus) before Every number that user cant delete.
>
> number length min 2 max 20
>
> only number,backspace, Arrowkey allow

Right now I'm using this:

```js
function Validatenumber(event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9?.*+*]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (regex.test(key) || event.keyCode == 8) {
            return true;
         }
         else{
           event.preventDefault();
              return false;
         }
    }
```

Comment: java is not javascript

Comment: Why the `java` tag ? Have you check the related question ? There is already a lot of post about regexp or even other solution. SO is not here to provide you the regexp. Explain your test that doesn't work to explain the problem

Comment: Dear AxelH, i m working in spring boot with ajax so add java tag, and You are true many friend provide solution for number input but my query is different , i think u Didn't  read properly , or if u have any reference please comment here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got Right Answer , i know i m fresher and and i don't have enough knowledge but if u have than share with any one instead of finding mistake in Question , why u use this tag and blah blah ...**

> > https://github.com/stripe/jquery.mobilePhoneNumber

Check out this link for perfect answer of my question...

and thank You very much friends who answer my question or try to answer my question .. keep it up friends...

Answer (score 0):

Try this(Got this from my project).

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1    /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.evt;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 37 && charCode != 39) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I now how to use regex for number but how to add + before every number using regex or javascript

Comment: yes , and only first place , i got it but its in jquery ,if u know how to do in java-script than please share with me

Comment: You are trying to apply keypress event and regx validation together this is not good way to write code. Go with one option.

Comment: As par your question "Add +(plus) before Every number that user cant delete. number length min 2 max 20" you can use this regx  ^\+[0-9]{2,22}$

Comment: can u make it one demo for me  Please ??

Comment: For what @hardikshah?

Comment: As per my requirement i was try on your regx but no result ... so please make one page simple html demo that accept number with +(plus) at first place ...